# Is there a third party VPN client which supports L2TP/IPsec PSK?

Tags: android, vpn

Android built-in VPN options include L2TP/IPsec PSK. For some strange reason, I cannot connect to my personal home L2TP/IPsec VPN from my Android 8.1 Samsung tablet, even though I can connect from my Windows 10 laptop and from my iPad.

Is there a third party VPN client in the google app store which supports L2TP/IPsec? (I could not find one)

At this point I am looking for any existing solution, price and trackers notwithstanding. Realistically, I might be willing to spend up to $10 or possibly even more on such an app and trackers could be acceptable, but it all depends on the parameters of the app (including extra app functionality, store rating, number of downloads, depeloper reputation etc)

Comment: While waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to check with [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_vpn#group_420). I don't know which of the clients supports L2TP/IPsec, but at least the list narrows down possible candidates (which do not depend on a specific provider). PS: please also [edit] your question and specify how much you'd be willing to spend on the app if needed, and if "trackers inside" are acceptable (unfortunately, they are becoming almost omnipresent but IMHO should not be, especially in this section).

Comment: Thanks. At this point I am looking for **any** existing solution, price and trackers notwithstanding. Realistically, I might be willing to spend up to $10 or possibly even more on such an app and trackers could be acceptable, but it all depends on the parameters of the app (including extra app functionality, store rating, number of  downloads, depeloper reputation etc)

Comment: As many users don't read though all the comments, you'd better **[edit]** your question to include those facts – as I suggested with my previous comment :)

Comment: I need that too! Android 12 is a big crap and now only supports ikev2.... I will not buy all new hardware (routers, etc) because they decided that ikev2 is more secure! The system should support all and the user should decide what to use, not them! It's our risk!